# Why does my umask keep resetting to 000?

Tags: umask

When I login anew my umask is `002`. At least for a while. Then at some point, and I'm not sure when, it reverts to `000`. This is very inconvenient and I'm now constantly living in fear of dropping files and folders with strange permissions across my home directory.

The reversion to `000` can happen after minutes of use, or after days. A few weeks after I first installed ubuntu it happened quite a lot, then it cooled down, and just in the last few days this issue has reared its ugly head again.

I can set it back to `002` with `$ umask 002` but this only works for the current shell (as expected).

Some more information:

- The tty at ctrl-alt-f2 has a umask of `002` even when my f7 login is at `000`
- `/etc/profile` says that umask is now handled by pam_umask
- `/etc/login.defs` has `UMASK 022` and `USERGROUPS_ENAB yes`

I'm running
Ubuntu 13.10 with XMonad and (oh-my-)zsh.

In case this is useful, here's my `/etc/fstab`

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>                                    
# / was on /dev/sdb8 during installation                                                                  
UUID=96f989e0-ee94-4bff-9663-3fa479a83ad4 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sdb1 during installation                                                          
UUID=7682-B8AD  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
# swap was on /dev/sdb7 during installation                                                               
UUID=0d7d57af-9a31-481e-9da4-1032c94f57e9 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Here is an abridged version of my crontab from `crontab -l`

```
* * * * * cd /home/miles/code/Checkin/ && ./node_modules/.bin/coffee ./client.coffee -n attercop -h secret1.com -p 8888
* * * * * cd /home/miles/code/Checkin/ && ./node_modules/.bin/coffee ./client.coffee -n attercop -h secret2.com -p 8888
```

`client.coffee` is just a script that sends an http request.

And my root crontab from `sudo crontab -l` reports `no crontab for root`

Comment: That _is_ strange. Are you setting a `umask` value when mounting your `$HOME`? Check `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: My $HOME is on the same partition as / and I'm not setting it in fstab. I've edited my fstab into my question for reference.

Comment: What do you mean by “reverts to 000”? In what program do you observe that? If you open a terminal and run a shell, does the umask change inside that shell?

Comment: What is the output of `crontab -l` and `sudo crontab -l`.

Comment: You could get an idea of which processes are changing the umask and when with an [auditd](http://packages.ubuntu.com/auditd) rule: `sudo auditctl -A auditctl exit,always -S umask` and look in `/var/log/kern.log` for audit logs.

Comment: @Braiam A crontab wouldn't affect running processes (unless via ptrace, which would be extremely weird).

Comment: @Gilles I observe it in the terminal. I usually observe it by running commands which happen to create files/dirs like `./site build` and am surprised when those dirs have weird permissions. Then I type `umask` and the result is `000` (when the issue has happened, I just logged out and in so it's `002` for now.)

Comment: @Braiam I have edited my crontab into the question.

Comment: @Gilles I don't have auditd, should I install it from the `autitd` package? I have 4 possibly relevant lines in `/var/log/kern.log` which all say `setup_percpu: NR_CPUS:256 nr_cpumask_bits:256 nr_cpu_ids:8 nr_node_ids:1`

Comment: Invoking a new shell like so: `bash -x -l -i -c 'exit' 2>&1 | grep umask`and look for any errant `umask`'s coming from a configuration file.

Comment: @slm I doubt that would work since he use zsh. Well, it does work, but he has to be pending that he first has to run without the grep command or it could collide with the oh-my-zsh update script.

Comment: @Braiam - something similar could be done with `zsh`. `zsh -x -l -i -c 'exit' 2>&1 | grep umask`.

Comment: @Miles Yes, you would install the auditd package. But that's probably not necessary: given that you're observing this in zsh, the most likely explanation by far is that you have a stray call to `umask` somewhere in your zsh configuration, and you'll find it by looking through your `.zshrc` and other zsh files.

Comment: Aha! Thank you for all of your gracious help. I have found the issue and will post an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue for me was caused by a Sublime Text 3 plugin called Terminal, which is used to launch terminals from sublime files. When Terminal launched the *first and only* window of gnome-terminal, then it inherited the umask of `000` from sublime.

In the hopes that this answer can be useful to those who are not having the same problem as me, I will reiterate some suggestions for how to attack this problem, garnered from the comments above:

- Look through your rc files (`.bashrc`, `.zshrc`) to see if there are errant `umask` calls.
- If you're using bash, try `bash -x -l -i -c 'exit' 2>&1 | grep umask` to find call to umask from your rc files.
- If you're using zsh, try `zsh -x -l -i -c 'exit' 2>&1 | grep umask` to find calls to `umask` from your rc files.
- Check whether you are setting a umask value when mounting `$HOME`. Look in `/etc/fstab`
- Check whether there is anything strange running in cron that could change your umask. 
  `crontab -l` and `sudo crontab -l`.
- Perhaps try using `audit` to find the source of mysterious umask changes.
  `sudo auditctl -A auditctl exit,always -S umask` and look in `/var/log/kern.log`

Comment: Since `bash -x -l -i -c 'exit' 2>&1 | grep umask` does not output the filename, using `grep -5 umask` leaves some additional context lines which can help pinpoint the file.